# Quantitative Skorokhod embedding

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, real-analysis, brownian-motion

The Skorokhod embedding theorem says that any random variable $X$ with $\mathbb E X=0$ and $\mathbb E[X^2]<\infty $ can be written as $X=B_{\tau }$ where $B$ is a Brownian motion and $\tau $ is a stopping time. The question is the following: Suppose I know that $X$ is very close to a standard normal random variable. Can I say that in this case $\tau $ can be chosen to be very close to $1$?

More precisely, suppose that there is a coupling of $X$ and $N\sim N(0,1)$ such that almost surely $|X-N|\le \epsilon $.  Can you find in this case a stopping time $\tau $ such that $X=B_{\tau }$ and also $Var(\tau )\le C \epsilon ^4$?

Comment: Do you want $tau$ to be a stopping time?

Comment: Have you thought along the lines of the embedding given by th 42 in II.8 of Phil Protter's book ?  You get the stopping (somewhat) explicitly, and it embeds a normal r.v. by just stopping at time 1, which is nice.

Comment: Are you talking about the book "stochastic integration and differential equations"? The theorem talks about embedding a Brownian motion inside a continuous martingale. By the way, there is also the construction of Root that is known to have the minimal variance (and the stopping time is 1 when X is normal). Root's result says that any distribution can be obtained by taking the stopping time to be the first time $(t,B_t)$ enters a certain barrier R. R is some subset of the plane

Comment: i don't know, but i would ask Prof Young-Heon Kim at UBC.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks. You have four more days to get the bounty :)